# How to install Win10 without any phyton stuff?

Tags: windows-10, installation

when I use Win10 medium USB and Media Creation Tool on my Acer laptop
completely reinstall is after starting the antivirus protection
disable, also the aliases for 3 programs with phyton.exe
activated and with advanced system settings the "connection with
Allow a remote computer "checked.

Downloaded from Microsoft of course, but also got a CD with code
wanted to install the latest version directly so I have a usb
stick formatted, downloaded the media creation tool to microsoft
and then even formatted during the installation on the old acer laptop
before installation

Allow VPN when roaming was also activated ...

Do I have a virus in my BIOS?

Is it normal that antivirus is turned off after fresh windows 10 install and 3 phyton exe have permission of aliase I clicked "i dont have a key" and somehow it activated (old acer laptop with win7) but i also got a win10 CD with Key (very expensive 180 €) Normally no phyton.exe should be on a fresh installed windows 10 or?

Is the image on the usb stick compromised or even my bios of the acer? (bios version 1.30) Downloaded from Microsoft of course, I also had a CD with code but wanted to install the latest version straight away, so I formatted a usb stick, downloaded the media creation tool on microsoft and then even formatted it during the installation on the old acer laptop before the installation Hello, When I completely reinstall Win10 using USB and Media Creation Tool on my Acer laptop, the anti-virus protection is deactivated after starting. In addition, the aliases for 3 programs with phyton.exe is activated and "Allow connection to a remote computer" is activated in advanced system settings. https://ibb.co/vJY9Y9k

Answer (score 0):

> Is the image on the USB stick compromised or even my bios?

This seems unlikely.

> Normally, no `python.exe` should be on a fresh install of Windows 10 or... ?

Regarding the "apps" shown in your screenshot, Python is generally not installed until you install it. If you click either of those links and have never done so before, you should be prompted to install Python from the Microsoft store. [Microsoft has included these links by default in Windows since approximately May 2019](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-the-windows-10-may-2019-update/).

> How do I install Win10 without any Python stuff?

As noted, Python should not be installed unless you install it. Regarding the links you mention, my thought would be you might need to modify a current copy the Windows ISO if you want those links to the store removed. And the same goes for automatically activating any antivirus. However, I am not certain I would see much point, as it seems likely Microsoft would simply recreate the links with the next update and might very well turn off any antivirus by default as well (it's potentially more difficult to download things with antivirus turned on).